# Getting wrong Version from Assembly using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to retrieve every assembly version from a huge solution, but I found out when I open the assembly using dotpeek, It shows the real version and I'm able to `bindiredirect` using this number:

[image]

But from reflection the number is completely different using `Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion`:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Using `Assembly.GetName().Version`:

```
4.0.0.0
```

I've tried every possible version that I was able to find, with the code below, but none of them bring the right number.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(f);
AssemblyName thisAssemName = assembly.GetName();
Version version = thisAssemName.Version;
FileVersionInfo fileversion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(f);

var multipleVersion = fileversion.ProductVersion
    + "|" + version
    + "|" + assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion
    + "|" + assembly;
```

I don't know the magic behind dotpeek, but It has the right thing. How can I retrieve the same number as the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dotpeek does not have any magic here. It's just a very-very confusing name and behavior for `Assembly.LoadFile(string path)` method. `Assembly.LoadFile()` does not actually load the assembly at specified path, it would prefer GAC like described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom/). You could check the actual path of loaded assembly with [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or similar tool.

If you want to load assembly at exact path for reflection purposes, it's better to use `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()` method:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(f);
```

In this case `assembly.GetName().Version` should give you the correct assembly version.